# ResourceManager can't get value by specified key

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, resourcemanager

I'm trying to get some values from `Resource`. But each time it gives me the following error :

> [MissingManifestResource_NoNeutralAsm]
>   Arguments: FreakyBoss.Client.Resources.Language.resources,FreakyBoss.Client
>   Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.60401.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=MissingManifestResource_NoNeutralAsm

My code is something like this :

```
    private readonly ResourceManager _resourceManager;
    public TranslationProvider() {
        _resourceManager = new ResourceManager("FreakyBoss.Client.Resources.Language", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
    public string GetResourceValue(string key) {
        return _resourceManager.GetString(key);
    }
```

My solution structure :

[image]

I don't know what's the problem. I've two resource files as you can see in the image above.
I think there is a problem with `BaseName` argument of constructor in `ResourceManager`.
But I don't know how should I fix this problem.

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you need to have a default resource and then add in the language specific resources. So in your case you would have (assuming en is default):

- Language.resx
- Language.fa.resx

The resource file already has all the code generated so you shouldn't have to write the code to generate the resource manager. Just access the Language.ResourceManager property.